# Installer Cabinet File is corrupt and cannot be used. (WIX)

Tags: wix, installation

Every once in a while, when compiling my WIX installer project, I will get the following error:

The cabinet file 'cab1.cab' required for this installation is corrupt and cannot be used. this could indicate an network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM or a problem with this package

I use an embedded media template ().

Is this just something that happens occasionally, or is there a way around it?

I am running the latest WiX toolset (v3.9.1208.0)

Thank you!

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hm, so I just changed the order of the files within my component (two AppX and a certificate), and it started to work once again. Odd ...